# video imagePickerController cancel not working

Tags: swift, video, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using custom CropViewController open source imagePicker for photos, and for video I'm trying to use default imagePicker provided by Swift itself since CropViewController doesn't have video option.

After I pick a video from photo library, three buttons shown at the bottom (cancel, play, select). Play button and select button works perfectly but cancel won't work.

Here is my code to trigger imagePickerController for both photo and video.

```
@objc func videoPresentPicker() {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String]
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

@objc func photoPresentPicker() {
        self.croppingStyle = .default
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = self
        picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        picker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am truly appreciated for you help. I have been struggling for few days and finally reaching out for some helps...

Update

```
extension ChatViewController: CropViewControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    internal func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let videoUrl = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? NSURL {
            let data = NSData(contentsOf: videoUrl as URL)!
            print("File size before compression: \(Double(data.length / 1048576)) mb")
            let compressedURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + NSUUID().uuidString + ".m4v")
            self.compressVideo(inputURL: videoUrl as URL, outputURL: compressedURL) { (exportSession) in
                guard let session = exportSession else {
                    return
                }
                switch session.status {
                case .unknown:
                    break
                case .waiting:
                    break
                case .exporting:
                    break
                case .completed:
                    guard let compressedData = NSData(contentsOf: compressedURL) else {
                        return
                    }
                    print("File size after compression: \(Double(compressedData.length / 1048576)) mb")
                case .failed:
                    break
                case .cancelled:
                    break
                @unknown default:
                    break
                }
            }
        } else {
            guard let image = (info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage) else { return }
            let cropController = CropViewController(croppingStyle: croppingStyle, image: image)
            cropController.delegate = self

            imageView.image = image

            picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                self.present(cropController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                if self.inputTextField.isFirstResponder == true {
                    self.handleKeyboardWillShow()
                }

            })
        }
        transparentView.alpha = 0
        self.tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this function

```
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: thank you for recommend this, I have implemented this function and still not working. I have updated a code with your recommendation. Please check if I have put your code in right place.

Comment: Then you need to implement the same function but for your CropViewController library. In the code you posted you are not presenting any UIImagePickerController but just a CropViewController

Comment: You have an example here with some dismiss actions : https://github.com/TimOliver/TOCropViewController/blob/master/Swift/CropViewControllerExample/ViewController.swift

Comment: Sorry, i may need some time to understand your answer. I'm new to Swift. Thank you I will try to interpret what your answers are :)